# (PsychoPy) Cannot assign fixed (independent of RT) duration to rating scale component

Tags: psychopy

For my fMRI experiment, I would like to have a rating window of a fixed 4s duration, i.e.
1) if a response is given in this window, the component stays active (marker is displayed) for the remaining time, i.e. 4-rt
2) if no response is given in this window, the component ends and the script moves on to the next trial

I've set the duration property of my rating scale component to 4s, but the scale still awaits a response indefinitely. The maxTime property is of no help, as that just deactivates the component rather than end it.

On the other hand, if a response is given, the component ends right then, making the rating window effectively of variable duration, which I do not want.

I've defined a blank text component to stay on the screen for 4-ratingScale.rt and thus act as a "buffer" that makes the total duration fixed. But I get the error "AttributeError: 'RatingScale' object has no attribute 'rt'". If instead of .rt I use .getRT(), I do get a value, however it does not seem to correspond to the time passed between the scale being displayed and a response being given.

Thanks for any thoughts!

Comment: You can add a snippet of code in a code component to force the end of the routine at 4 s (e.g. `if t >= 4.0: continueRoutine = False` But there are issues in an fMRI experiment with the resulting small timing errors accumulating, and this needs to be accounted for. You should perhaps ask this question on http://discourse.psychopy.org where PsychoPy community  support is now more comprehensive and timely than here at StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks,I'll ask a separate question there about the cumulative errors. But as for the rating scale component ending after a set number of seconds: isn't that something that its "duration" field should control? The code you suggest seems to end the entire routine whereas I just want the ratingScale to end.

Comment: Also, any thoughts on retrieving the time it took for a rating to be made? I was surprised that ratingScale.rt was not recognised, and that ratingScale.getRT() returns something unexpected (values much smaller or much larger than the actual time taken to respond)

Comment: please let me know if you can still help with these follow-ups, thanks!

Comment: Those issues with the rating scale component indicate something unusual. The best help here will be on the Discourse forum: the rating scale isn't something I'm too familiar with.

Comment: I have asked there too, but no-one has replied for the past 3 days :(